# Why won't my iPhone Apps appear in iTunes 12.5.5 on El Cap?

Tags: ios, itunes, macos, applications, iphone

I have an older (2011-2012) MackBook Pro running El Capitan (10.11.6) and iTunes 12.5.5 (in other words, the latest of both).  I have an iPhone SE running iOS 10.1.1.

I don't use this MBP very often, but I happen to be doing some mobile music recording, and I need to get a file out of a specific application on my phone (Propellerhead Figure) and onto my MBP.  The only way to do this, is via the app's file-sharing via iTunes.  I've done this plenty of times before on my Desktop mac, but not on my MBP until now.

Unfortunately, my phone does not seem to sync at all with the MBP.  The computer is authorized to my iCloud account, and the sync looks like it's working but completes in a couple of seconds, and no apps are brought over.  The images of each of my phone's screens show all the apps, but no apps are actually transferred to the MBP.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what to do about it?  I've been googling like crazy but coming up empty.  I've got to get this working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WOAH I did not expect to be answering my own question so fast.  But in case anyone else ever runs into this, here is what just fixed it for me.

I had an old iPhone 4s laying around (iOS 8.x) so decided to see if it would sync.  Hooked it up and sure enough, no problem... apps came over, etc.  Plugged my iPhone SE back in (in addition to the 4s still connected), selected the SE, and lo & behold - all my apps show up.  I can't explain it as they were never transferred to the computer... but there are there and I can access the file I needed.  Very strange!